# vncserver becomes unresponsive to keyboard and mouse after a few minutes, but the screen still updates

Tags: 20.04, vnc, tightvncserver

Everything used to work fine on 18.04 LTS. I upgraded a while ago and started having problems with vnc. The display will continue to update as the screen contents change, but my mouse and keyboard inputs are ignored after a few minutes. I connect to other hosts with no problem so it's not my client. Here is some supporting info:

`/etc/X11/Xvnc-session`:

```
#!/bin/sh

#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &

# Fix to make GNOME and GTK stuff work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

xfce4-session &

# before Ubuntu 18.04:
# gnome-settings-daemon &

# Ubuntu 18.04 and later:
/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-xsettings &
```

.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ vncserver -version
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.

Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
```

Comment: The workaround has been to use xrdp instead of vnc and that's working fine.